# Well-Ordering Principle From Recursion Theorem

Tags: recursion, constructive-mathematics, well-orders, intuitionistic-logic

As far as I understand, in intuitionistic logic we have neither (i) the [well-ordering principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle) nor (ii) the [recursion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#The_recursion_theorem).  But can one deduce one from the other?  I believe we cannot deduce (ii) from (i), but assume (ii) holds and $P:\mathbf{N}\to\Omega$ is a subset of $\mathbf{N}$.  If $P(0)$ then $0$ is the smallest element in $P$ and we are done.  Else we can define $f:\mathbf{N}\to\mathbf{N}$ via $f(0)=0$ and $$f(n+1)=\begin{cases}f(n)>0&f(n)\\P(n+1)&n+1\\0&\text{else}\end{cases}$$
If $P$ is non-empty, we get $p\in P$ (by constructive definition of non-empty) and can define the smallest element of $P$ as $f(p)$.  Would this work out?

My second question would be, what do intuitionists think about the recursion theorem?  To me it feels a bit more constructive than proofs by contradiction, although you prove it by contradiction (as far as I remember) in classical set theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $P : \mathbf{N} \to \mathbf{2}$ is a *decidable* subset of $\mathbf{N}$, and you are given $m : \mathbf{N}$ such that $P(m) = 1$, then yes, you can use $P$ to calculate a lowest value of $n : \mathbf{N}$ such that $P(n) = 1$.  On the other hand, the well-ordering principle for arbitrary subsets of $\mathbf{N}$ would in fact imply excluded middle.  To see this, suppose $p : \Omega$ is a proposition, and define the subset
$$P := \{ n : \mathbf{N} \mid n=1 \lor (n=0 \land p) \}.$$
Then $1 \in P$, so $P$ is nonempty and the minimum element of $P$ must be either 0 or 1.  However, if the minimum element is 0, then we conclude $p$, while if the minimum element is 1, then we conclude $\lnot p$.  (This does make use of the fact that $\{ n : \mathbf{N} \mid n \le 1 \} = \{ 0, 1 \}$, which is straightforward to prove assuming the validity of definitions by recursion.)

For your second question: yes, defining functions on $\mathbf{N}$ by recursion is widely considered to be intuitionistically valid.  For instance, the definition of a natural numbers object in a topos essentially says exactly that this is valid.  Also, related to the computability interpretation of intuitionism, computer programmers define functions by recursion all the time.

Answer (score 2):

The recursion theorem is perfectly constructively valid. In fact, in some versions of constructive mathematics, the recursion theorem is actually an axiom.

The well-ordering principle, as it’s classically stated, is equivalent to the law of excluded middle. For consider a proposition $Q$. Define $S = \{x \in \{0, 1\} \mid x = 1 \lor Q\}$. Then $S$ has a least element if and only if $Q \lor \neg Q$. For if $S$’s least element is $0$, then $Q$. And if $S$’s least element is 1, then $\neg Q$.

Your proof doesn’t work because you assume either $P(0)$ or $\neg P(0)$.